# Unable to find jsoup jar in repository based on its sha-1

Tags: maven, nexus, sonatype

When I perform an advanced search based on the sha-1 on http://search.maven.org/#advancedsearch for jsoup - jsoup-1.6.1.jar the jar file is not found.
The sha-1 for jsoup-1.6.1.jar is b65281e9d00f255cdfab9e1880f7fc7a1fb1bffb so the advanced search becomes : http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7C1%3A%22b65281e9d00f255cdfab9e1880f7fc7a1fb1bffb%22

But no results are found ?

The jsoup jar does exist on the repository so either the generated sha-1 is incorrect or the maven repository search is not finding this jar based on its sha-1, for what reason I do not know ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how you determined the hash for `jsoup-1.6.1.jar`.

I get the following:

```
fciv  -sha1 jsoup-1.6.1.jar
//
// File Checksum Integrity Verifier version 2.05.
//
70f0dfbe511d84ee7d0dda238a52746751787c47 jsoup-1.6.1.jar
```

This matches the [hash file](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jsoup/jsoup/1.6.1/jsoup-1.6.1.jar.sha1) in the repository.

When I use [this](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7C1%3a%2270f0dfbe511d84ee7d0dda238a52746751787c47%22), the advance search does bring up the jar.

Comment: Ok, I wonder if the jsoup file im using has been tampered with somehow as its generating a different checksum than the same jar in the repository.